# Need help understanding a complex query with multiple join conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a query that I am trying to understand. Can someone shed light on to the details of what this query does?
I've only ever used one `ON` clause in a join condition. This one has multiple conditions for the `LEFT JOIN`, making it tricky to understand.

```
INSERT INTO nop_tbl
          (q_date, community_id, newsletter_t, subscription_count)     
  SELECT date(now()), a.community_id, 
     a.newsletter_type, 
     count(a.subscriber_user_id)
   FROM
      newsletter_subscribers_main a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN nop_tbl b
       ON (a.community_id = b.community_id)
       AND (a.newsletter_type = b.newsletter_t)
       AND (a.created_at = b.q_date)
   WHERE b.q_date is null
   AND   b.mailing_list is null
GROUP BY a.community_id, a.newsletter_t, a.created_at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your explanation:

The objective of the query is to count subscriptions per `(q_date, community_id, newsletter_t)` in `newsletter_subscribers_main` and write the result to `nop_tbl`.
The `LEFT JOIN` prevents that rows are added multiple times.

But I also think, the query is inefficient and **probably wrong**.

- The 2nd `WHERE` clause:

  ```
  AND   b.mailing_list is null
  ```

  is just noise and can be removed. If `b.q_date is null`, then `b.mailing_list` is guaranteed to be null in this query.
- You don't need parentheses around `JOIN` conditions.
- If `subscriber_user_id` is defined `NOT NULL`, `count(*)` does the same, cheaper.
- I suspect that grouping by `a.created_at`, while you insert `date(now())` is probably wrong. Hardly makes any sense. My **educated guess** (assuming that `created_at` is type `date`):

```
INSERT INTO nop_tbl
      (q_date, community_id, newsletter_t, subscription_count)     
SELECT a.created_at
      ,a.community_id
      ,a.newsletter_type
      ,count(*)
FROM   newsletter_subscribers_main a
LEFT   JOIN nop_tbl b ON a.community_id = b.community_id
                     AND a.newsletter_type = b.newsletter_t
                     AND a.created_at = b.q_date
WHERE  b.q_date IS NULL
GROUP  BY a.created_at, a.community_id, a.newsletter_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

The short short version is:

1. `insert ... select ...`
   -> the query is filling `nob_tbl`
2. `from ...`
   -> based on data in `newsletter_subscribers_main`
3. `left join ... where ... is null`
   -> that are not already present in `nob_tbl`

Comment: THanks for such a highlevel quick overview. If i run this, it reloads the data again and again. How can I make this idempotent?

Comment: The query looks like the kind of thing you run to fill in blanks. There might indeed be a slight issue with the join or the where clause. It's a bit hard to tell without knowing what you're trying to do exactly, but my guess would be to remove `b.q_date`-related clauses in the join/where clauses, and to add `and b.community_id is null` to the where clause, to make it match the join clause. Run the query without the insert part (the first two lines you posted) to run tests.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step

```
INSERT INTO nop_tbl
      (q_date, community_id, newsletter_t, subscription_count)
```

The [`INSERT` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) This is telling the database in what table and what column will be used for the insert query

```
SELECT date(now()), a.community_id, 
       a.newsletter_type, 
       count(a.subscriber_user_id)
```

Those are instead the [selected](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) fields to insert

```
FROM
newsletter_subscribers_main a
```

Here is telling to the database to select fields which has alias prepended `a.` from table `newsletter_subscribers_main`

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN nop_tbl b
```

Here is left joining another table `nop_tbl` where other fields will be selected

```
ON (a.community_id = b.community_id)
AND (a.newsletter_type = b.newsletter_t)
AND (a.created_at = b.q_date)
```

Those are the rules of the [**`JOIN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), actually is telling what columns will be used for join

```
WHERE b.q_date is null
AND   b.mailing_list is null
```

Those are the [**`WHERE`** clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html) , they are used to limit result to the requested data, in this case where two columns are null

```
GROUP BY a.community_id, a.newsletter_t, a.created_at
```

[**`GROUP BY`** clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html), used to group result on given column

You can have a visual explanation of [**joins here**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: i need help with the joins more. The join on multiple columns and that too left joins..