# Idempotent INSERT not working as expected. Is my query logic faulty?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, sql-insert

I am expecting this to not insert data every time I execute this statement. It should only insert data effectively once a day. Thats what I want this to do. Is there something wrong with my logic here? I am using `date(now())` so that it inserts todays date. I need this to be an idempotent insert.

```
INSERT INTO newsletter_subscription_counts
          (query_date, community_id, mailing_list, subscription_count)
  SELECT date(now()), a.community_id, 
     a.newsletter_type::mail_list_types, 
     count(a.subscriber_user_id)
   FROM
      newsletter_subscribers_main a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN newsletter_subscription_counts b
   ON (a.community_id = b.community_id)
   AND (a.newsletter_type::mail_list_types = b.mailing_list)
   AND (a.created_at = b.query_date)
   WHERE b.query_date is null
   AND   b.mailing_list is null
GROUP BY a.community_id, a.newsletter_type, a.created_at
```

Comment: If you are using Postgresql please don't use the SQL Server and Oracle tags.

Comment: Sorry i figured the SQL I was using was for the most part almost exact in sqlserver/oracle. I wanted to tap into the tallent of those SQL experts too.

Comment: It might help to share a simple set of table data that exemplifies the problem.  Note: Having the `GROUP BY` not be an inner query on just subscribers makes me uneasy...  and wouldn't you want to group by `DATE(a.created_at)`?

Comment: The **table definitions** showing types, NOT NULL constraints, etc. would go a long way ...

Comment: @user2081579 Well, if they're interested in generic SQL they're following the `sql` tag already... and if they're not, they're probably not interested in the question. Please just stick to the tags appropriate for describing the real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO newsletter_subscription_counts
      (query_date, community_id, newsletter_t, subscription_count)     
SELECT now()::date
      ,a.community_id
      ,a.newsletter_type
      ,count(*)
FROM   newsletter_subscribers_main a
LEFT   JOIN newsletter_subscription_counts b
                     ON  a.community_id = b.community_id
                     AND a.newsletter_type::mail_list_types = b.mailing_list
                     AND a.created_at = b.query_date
WHERE  a.created_at::date = now()::date
AND    b.query_date is null
GROUP  BY a.community_id, a.newsletter_type;
```

Removed some noise, improved format and most importantly added the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE  a.created_at::date = now()::date
```

If `created_at` is already type `date`, you don't need the cast.

Also consider my answer to your previous question, where I already guessed your problem:
[Need help understanding a complex query with multiple join conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151003/need-help-understanding-a-complex-query-with-multiple-join-conditions/17152529#17152529)

Only, my guess over there takes care of **all days** that have not been inserted yet (and is preferable IMO).

Comment: Instead of `now()::date`, just use `current_date`.

Comment: @CraigRinger: It's the same. I prefer `now()::date`, just because it's tiny bit shorter and faster, when portability to other RDBMS is not being relevant.